# Ajax call to controller function returning empty response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a dropdown and whenever the value changes I am calling a javascript function to change some values. I am using Codeigniter, and in javascript, I have used ajax and made ajax call to controller function. the response is "success", but it is empty, and even if I write echo "hi" in the controller the response is empty.

ajax_operations.php

```
function getInventory()
    {   echo "hi";
        $table                          ="inventory"
        $inventoryRecordOptionsData     = "";
        $inventoryRecords               = array();
        $option                         ="item_name";

        if($this->input->post('storeId') != "" ){

            //$inventoryRecords = $this->base_model->fetch_records_from($table, array(store_id => $this->input->post('storeId')));
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id, item_name FROM dt_inventory WHERE store_id = 34");
            $inventoryRecords = $query->result_array();

            //$inventoryRecords = $this->db->get_where($table,array('store_id' => '35')->result();
            if(count($inventoryRecords) > 0) {

                $inventoryRecordOptionsData = '<option value="">Select '.$option.'</option>';

                foreach($inventoryRecords as $ic) {

                    $inventoryRecordOptionsData = $inventoryRecordOptionsData . '<option value="'.$ic->id.'">'.$ic->item_name.'</option>';

                }

            }
            else{
                $inventoryRecordOptionsData='<option value="">Select '.$option.'</option>';
            }

        }
        echo $option;
        //echo $inventoryRecordOptionsData;

    }
```

javascript function

```
function getInventoryRecords(store_id)
   { //alert(store_id);
       var childId = "items";
       var optionTxt = "items";

       if(store_id > 0) {

       $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/ajax_operations/getInventory",
        data: "storeId="+store_id+"",

        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {


            if(data) {

                $('#'+childId).empty();
                $('#'+childId).append(data);

            } else {
                console.log("hi"+data+"hello");
                $('#'+childId).empty();
                alert("empty response");
                $('#'+childId).append('<option value="">No '+optionTxt+' available.</option>');
            }
            $('#'+childId).trigger("liszt:updated");
        }

       });

       } else {

       $('#'+childId).empty();
       $('#'+childId).append('<option value="">Select '+optionTxt1+' First.</option>');
       $('#'+childId).trigger("liszt:updated");
       }
 }
```

I am getting "SUCCESS" as status. but the data is empty.

Comment: add the error function to you ajax call and send the output to the console.

Comment: it is entering success function. and triggered alert as "empty response"

Comment: any help????????

Comment: you should try like this `$jdata=array('status'=>'success','data'=>$option); echo json_encode($jdata);`

Comment: even if i create a function with only one line "echo "hi" " its showing empty response

Comment: You are using url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/ajax_operations/getInventory", but you actually want ajax_operation.php and use getInventory(). The ajax call will not involve the codeigniter url parsing to get to the true area the you want. You will need to write some additional code url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/ajax_operations.php&getInventory" then in the ajax_operation.php find what the parameter is and then call it.

Comment: url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/ajax_operations.php&getInventory" is giving error 400